# react native: Not able to parse json params

Tags: json, react-native

I created a class to get api.

```
export default class ProductDetail extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        product : []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProductRequest();
  }
  ...
```

then create getProductRequest function:

```
async getProductRequest() {
      let response = await fetch('https: ...
      let json = await response.json();
      console.log(json);
      this.setState({ product : json.data});
  }
```

the console result is:

> {id: 225782, title: "test", images: Array(1), price: "1$"}

Now in render i get same result:

```
render() {

console.log(this.state.product);

return (...
```

Now I try to read params:

```
render() {

console.log(this.state.product.title);

return (...
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of underfined

what's the wrong?

**Edit: Structure:**

```
export default class ProductDetail extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        product : []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProductRequest();
  }

  render() {


    console.log(this.state.product.title);

    return (
      <View>  <Text style={styles.name}>title</Text></View>

    );
  }

  async getProductRequest() {
    try {

        let id = this.props.navigation.state.params.productId;
        let response = await 
              fetch('https://www.example.com/product', {
              method : 'POST',
              headers : {
                  'Accept' : 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
              },
              body : JSON.stringify({
                  id
              })
          });
        let json = await response.json();
        //json: {"data":{id: 225782, title: "test", images: Array(1), price: "1$"},"status":"success"}

        this.setState({ product : json.data});

    } catch(error) {
        //console.log(error)
    }
  }
}

...
```

Comment: Can you post your render function as well? I assume you are accessing title from your product before it is ready.

Also I am unsure why you are setting json.data as your product even though json already seems to be your product.

Comment: @Areza replace `<View>  <Text style={styles.name}>title</Text></View>`
with this `<View>  <Text style={styles.name}>this.state.product.title</Text></View>`

Answer (score 0):

Because, `componentDidMount()` re-render after the first execution of rendering. So, when you are putting `console.log(this.state.product.title);` in the render before return, it doesn't get the title param first time.

After the re-render, the value will be available. So, if you want to check the output put `console.log` elsewhere or just remove it

**Edit**

You can call `this.getProductRequest();` in componentWillMount() instead of componentDidMount()

```
 componentWillMount() {
    this.getProductRequest();
  }
```

Comment: Also I can get data by this: `console.log(this.state.product)` in `render()`. I have problem with `console.log(this.state.product.title)`

Comment: Have you run removing the console.log()?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let product = JSON.parse(this.state.product
     if(product.title){
        console.log(product.title)
     }
```

Let with above code. If you are getting string in your state, it may create an issue. Let me know if its work.

Answer (score 0):

As said react official documentation :

`componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree`)

it does mean that first time your render method is unable to read the title of your product (first time that your render method is invoked, this.state.product is still an empty array). I suggest you to check if your array is empty

```
render() {

  if (this.state.product) {
    return (
           <Text>Loading...</Text>
  } else
  return (
    <View><Text>{this.state.product.title}</Text></View>
  )
}
```

Don't use `componentWillMount()` because these methods are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code.
[componentWillMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

Answer (score -1):

If your render function actually does look like you posted, then this can't work. Try chaning your render function to something like this.

```
render() {
  const { product } = this.state
  if (!product || !product.title) {
    return null
  }
  return (
    <View><Textstyle={styles.name}>product.title</Text></View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The returned json is `{"data":{id: 225782, title: "test", images: Array(1), price: "1$"},"status":"success"}` so I used `product : json.data` also In view I test it with `console.log()` in `render()`